# Strongloop installation are not finished

Tags: node.js, npm, strongloop

I try to install [Strongloop](http://strongloop.com/get-started/) with ***npm install -g strongloop*** command. But during the installation procces it stoped on moment bellow. Another globally packages are installed without a problems.

[image].

Is there any ideas why it can be?

Comment: The node-syslog module is an optional dependency that doesn't support Windows, so it should be failing and continuing on with the rest of the dependencies. Do you have cygwin installed?

Comment: You could try installing with `npm install -g --no-optional strongloop` and it will skip installing optional dependencies like node-syslog.

Comment: You may be running into this known issue, could you provide more details on - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6502

Comment: Ryan, i compile modules with VS2012 compilator if im not wrong it gave me same result. I try to install with --no-optional flag but nothing changed, it freeze the same as on picture above

Comment: update the discussion on github https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6502

Comment: I've instaled strongloop successfully, the problem was in old version of npm, upgrade to npm2 solve this problem